# Get properties for an object returned by Get-AzResource on Azure

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying get the properties of an Azure Disk Resource. When I run the command in my subscription

```
$R=Get-AzResource -Name <ResourceName>
```

It provides a list of properties given  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.commands.resourcemanager.cmdlets.sdkmodels.psresource?view=az-ps-latest) I am specifically interested getting the Properties PSobject. However running the following command:

```
$R.Properties -eq $null
```

does returns true. When I look at this resource from Azure Portal (Same user principal as in Powershell command) in Json format I am given a selection of schemas to choose from and lots of properties are provided. Below is a sample:

```
"properties": {
        "osType": "Linux",
        "hyperVGeneration": "V2",
        "supportsHibernation": true,
        "supportedCapabilities": {
            "acceleratedNetwork": true,
            "architecture": "x64"
        },
        "creationData": {
            "createOption": "FromImage",
            "imageReference": {
                "id": "xxx"
            }
        },
        "diskSizeGB": 30,
        "diskIOPSReadWrite": 500,
        "diskMBpsReadWrite": 60,
        "encryption": {
            "type": "EncryptionAtRestWithPlatformKey"
        },
        "networkAccessPolicy": "AllowAll",
        "publicNetworkAccess": "Enabled",
        "timeCreated": "2023-01-09T13:38:24.500223+00:00",
        "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
        "diskState": "Attached",
        "diskSizeBytes": 32213303296,
        "uniqueId": "xxx"
```

What is the proper command to get this information using PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

You should set the ExpandProperties switch

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azresource?view=azps-9.3.0#-expandproperties

```
$resourceWithProperties = Get-AzResource -Name <ResourceName> -ExpandProperties
```

You can the access the properties with

```
$resourceWithProperties.Properties
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can get all properties using `-ExapandProperties` command and Alternative way of getting all properties is by using below commands:**

```
Connect-AzAccount

$disk = Get-AzResource -ResourceId "/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<Rg name>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/<Diskname>"  
$disk.Properties | Format-List *
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]